# Remove Top and Bottom Padding

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following table: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FM993ZP563E4

I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the distance between the lists. How would it be possible to get rid of the padding while still having the second column milliwatts align with the corresponding root list items?

Table for reference:
[image]

Comment: Can you view the codes? You might try to put `<td style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `ul` which has a default `margin` top and bottom, so you have to add:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

And it should work.

Check the [updated example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FM99E71JNP0D).

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you need to remove the padding (and margin for older browsers) from the `ul` element. Then you can get rid of the `20px` top padding on the `.parent` class:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.used {
  text-align: right;
}
td ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
.parent {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:80%;">
  <tr>
    <td class="td">
      <ul>
        <li>Some Module Name
          <ul>
            <li>Some Module Name <strong>(300mW)</strong>
              <li>Some Module Name <strong>(700mW)</strong>
                <ul>
                  <li>Some Module Name <strong>(300mW)</strong>
                </ul>
          </ul>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td class="td parent">
      <strong>1000mW</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td">
      <ul>
        <li>Some Module Name
          <ul>
            <li>Some Module Name <strong>(300mW)</strong>
              <li>Some Module Name <strong>(700mW)</strong>
                <ul>
                  <li>Some Module Name <strong>(300mW)</strong>
                </ul>
          </ul>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td class="td parent">
      <strong>1000mW</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="td">
      <ul>
        <li>Some Module Name <strong>1000mW</strong>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td class="td parent">
      <strong>1000mW</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>John</th>
      <td class="used"><strong>1000mW</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```css
table * {margin:0;padding:0 auto;box-sizing:border-box} /* to reset the defaults of all the elements inside the table */

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.used {
  text-align: right;
}

.parent {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*padding-top: 20px;*/
}
```

```html
<table style="width:80%;">
 <tr>
     <td class="td">
         <ul>
             <li>Some Module Name
                <ul>
                 <li>Some Module Name <strong>(300mW)</strong>
                    <li>Some Module Name <strong>(700mW)</strong>
                    <ul>
                     <li>Some Module Name <strong>(300mW)</strong>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="td parent">
           <strong>1000mW</strong>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td  class="td">
             <ul>
             <li>Some Module Name 
                <ul>
                 <li>Some Module Name <strong>(300mW)</strong>
                    <li>Some Module Name <strong>(700mW)</strong>
                    <ul>
                     <li>Some Module Name <strong>(300mW)</strong>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="td parent">
           <strong>1000mW</strong>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td  class="td">
            <ul>
             <li>Some Module Name <strong>1000mW</strong>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td class="td parent">
           <strong>1000mW</strong>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>John</th>
        <td class="used"><strong>1000mW</strong></td>
      </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```